# String in Java is object, so it should be reference?

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java, recently faced such an interview question on Java String concept:

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void changeStr(String str){
        str="welcome";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str="1234";
        changeStr(str);
        System.out.println(str);
     }
}
```

I think the output should be "welcome", however, I tested it in Eclipse, it showed "1234", isn't Java string is a reference, so the Java string "str" references gets changed to "welcome" in method changeStr?

Pardon me for the beginner question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object's reference is passed to the method and assigned to the parameter, which is a kind of local variable.

Assigning a different object reference to the parameter does nothing to the variable outside the method that held a reference to the original object.

Also String is immutable, so there's no way to change its value (for example a `setValue()` method).

Comment: thank you very much, now I know where I got wrong :).

Answer (score 2):

The line `str = "welcome";` doesn't change the value of any String - Strings can never change their values.  What it does is it makes one reference point to a different String.  But the reference that it reassigns is the one that's local to `changeStr`, not the one that is declared in `main`.

Comment: The **String str** and **String str="1234"** are not same one, they are two local variables live in stack. 
Both of those refer to string "1234" in String Constant Pool. But after assigning str="welcome", the **String str** reref to "welcome" and the **String str="1234"** still refer to "1234".
 The key in here, when you modifier a string means you create a new String not modifier itseft because String is immutable.

Comment: @qmn1711 it seems to me that you should post that as a separate answer, since it's so completely different from anything I said.

Comment: but I only understood this question after reading your comment. I think it has a connection :)

Answer (score 1):

String is a reference, but the key is that `String str` inside `changeStr` is a different reference than `str` in main. Add that to the fact that strings are immutable in Java (meaning that when you change a String, the reference points to a different location in memory) and that explains why main will print `1234`

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final StringHolder holder = new StringHolder("old value");
    System.out.println(holder);
    reassignHolder(holder);
    System.out.println(holder);
    changeVal(holder);
    System.out.println(holder);
}

static void reassignHolder(StringHolder holder) {
    holder = new StringHolder("new value");
}

static void changeVal(StringHolder holder) {
    holder.setVal("new value");
}

static class StringHolder {

    private String val;

    public StringHolder(String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public String getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StringHolder{" + "val=" + val + '}';
    }

}
```

In Java references are passed by value and (almost) everything is an object reference.

Here we have a mutable object that holds a `String` - a `StringHolder`.

When we call `reassignHolder` what we actually do is *copy* our object reference and pass it to the method. When the method reassigns the reference nothing happens to our original reference as we are passing a copy.

When we call `reassignHolder` we also pass a copy of our reference, but the method uses this reference to call a method on our object to change its `val` variable. This will have an effect.

So the output is:

```
StringHolder{val=old value}
StringHolder{val=old value}
StringHolder{val=new value}
```

As `String` is immutable, you can only carry out the first example rather than the second.

Answer (score 0):

The logic here is that the `str` value that is passed is passed as a copy of reference of  `str`. This implies that any change in `str` will not be reflected in the original `str`.
This situation is similar to **pass by value (but of references!)**

However in your code if you change the code to `str = new String("welcome");` It will change the original `str` string by making it reference a new copy that was created.

Hope this clears things for you.

Comment: I think you mean "a copy of a reference", not "a reference to a copy" in the first sentence.